# Docker: no space left on device

Tags: docker

I try to build a docker image with following Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/datascience-notebook
RUN pip install jupyterhub==0.8.0 && \
    pip install s3contents && \
    pip install nose dask toolz

# Install R kernel
RUN conda install -c r r-irkernel r-essentials r-base -y


# Install Data Science Package
RUN pip install sagemaker && \
    conda install -y pandas


COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /etc/jupyter/

CMD ["jupyterhub-singleuser"]
# build
# docker build -t singleuser --build-arg BASE_IMAGE=jupyter/scipy-notebook --build-arg JUPYTERHUB_VERSION=0.8.0 .
```

on a machine with 32G memory, 80G disk space, only used for this build

but error

```
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /opt/julia/v0.6/HDF5/deps/usr/include/H5overflow.h: no space left on device
```

result of df -a

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
proc                   0       0         0    - /proc
sysfs                  0       0         0    - /sys
devtmpfs        16461060      56  16461004   1% /dev
devpts                 0       0         0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs           16471592       0  16471592   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda1       8123812 1319984   6703580  17% /
devpts                 0       0         0    - /dev/pts
none                   0       0         0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/blkio
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/cpu
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/cpuacct
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/cpuset
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/devices
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/freezer
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/memory
cgroup                 0       0         0    - /cgroup/perf_event
/dev/xvda1       8123812 1319984   6703580  17% /var/lib/docker
```

Comment: 80G? If I'm reading the above right, it looks closer to 8G. What does `du -sh .` output in the build directory, and include `df -h` for comparison. Is this a desktop environment, vm, or bare metal Linux install?

Comment: @BMitch you are right. It's 8G. that was the problem :( ...